Angular workspace - Can import local build, cannot import pipeline artifact build
I have an Angular workspace common-web-modules, with two libraries common-components and common-services. I'm trying to use these two libraries in my angular application, my-app.
When I import the package from my registry into my-app, the compiler doesn't complain about not being able to find the imported services / components. But when I try and serve my-app, I get the following error.
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'common-web-modules/dist/common-services' in '...\src\app\modules\my-module'
When I create a local production build, copy the contents of the dist and paste it into the appropriate node_modules location in my-app, it works fine.
The only difference I see between the published build that is imported and the local build that is copy / pasted is the .npmignore and package.json files for each library aren't showing up in the published build. Is the lack of a package.json in the individual libraries the issue? If so, how do I include it in the pipeline build? My .yml file is running the exact same script I'm running locally.

Also of note, the individual library package.json files that are generated in the local build have a different structure than the package.json files that are in the libraries.
For example, projects/common-services/package.json looks like this:
{
  "name": "common-services",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "sideEffects": false
}

While the local build in dist/common-services/package.json looks like this:
{
  "name": "common-services",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "sideEffects": false,
  "module": "fesm2022/common-services.mjs",
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    "./package.json": {
      "default": "./package.json"
    },
    ".": {
      "types": "./index.d.ts",
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/common-services.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/common-services.mjs",
      "default": "./fesm2022/common-services.mjs"
    }
  }
}


Why do you have two separate libraries and not just one library with secondary entrypoints?
